# regular expression for full name input

Tags: jquery, regex

i am looking for a way to write a regex code to only check for minimum of 2 spaces & alphabets only.

This is what i have so far

```
var badre = /[^A-Za-z'-]/;
```

It is only checking if the input is other than alphabetical letters. My input is for full name so i am expecting something like 'Jason Kornell Bishop'.

i am thinking that as full name are hard to write a regex for. How can i specify to check for at least 2 spaces in the whole input and also alphabets only.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0):

> How can i specify to check for at least 2 spaces in the whole input and also alphabets only.

You can use:

```
var re = /^(?=(?:\S*\s){2})[A-Za-z ]+$/;
```

Here `(?=(?:\S*\s){2})` is a lookahead that ensures at least 2 spaces in input. Though it will also allow all spaces in input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex which checks for a minimum of 2 spaces and alphabets only.

```
^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

`check for minimum of 2 spaces & alphabets only`

RegEx -

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lH8uF3/5)